# Limit on max users and groups in Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

Is there a max limit on the number of users I can create/manage from a single admin account?
Is there a max limit on the number of groups I can create while managing those users ?
Is there a way to send additional params in the webhook url ?(I am configuring it through the docusign connect in admin portal) ?

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the only limit to the number of users is the number of seats you have purchased on your account. There's no technical limit.

I'm similarly not aware of any limit to the number of groups.

Now your last question is not clear and may require a separate thread. What kind of parameters you would like to send? from where to where? One method to include meta-data on envelopes is using custom fields, which can be sent to the webhook UI (Connect), but I'm not sure that is what you mean.